# How does Google Analytics calculate 10000 requests per Profile?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am Fetching Data from Google Analytics For Metrics (Pageviews,Unique pageviews, TimeonPAge, Exits) as below

```
 DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest r = GAS.Data.Ga.Get(profileID,startdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),enddate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),"ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:timeOnPage,ga:exits");
 r.Dimensions = "ga:pagePath";
 r.Filters = "ga:pagePath=~ItemID=" + strPagePath + "*";
 r.MaxResults = 1000;
 GaData d = r.Fetch();`
```

then I received the following exception after fetching data(Metrics) for some random number of videos:

```
>>Error while fetching pageviews From GA Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>>Quota Error: profileId ga:****** has exceeded the daily request limit. [403]
>>Errors [
>>  Message[Quota Error: profileId ga:****** has exceeded the daily request >>>limit.] Location[ - ] Reason[dailyLimitExceeded] Domain[global]
>>]
```

I am fetching these four metrics( page views, unique views.. so on) for one ItemID.

Does Google Analytics calculate it as 4 different Requests or one single request??

Answer (score 0):

Each request you send against the Google analytics API counts as one.   The Quota is not project or user based.

**Pagination:**

Your request above you are requesting maxResults of 1000 if the total number of rows in your request is 100000 then you are going to have to make 100 requests to get all of the data.

**All APIs:**

Requests to all of the APIs count against the same quota so if you are also using the management api it counts as well as the reporting api.

**All Users and applications:**

Now here is the fun part about the current quota system it is not project related.

Lets say my company has a profile 1234567.  Now our marketing team all has access.  Each member of the marketing team likes different apps. They all install the app they like best.    They are all using the same 10000 request quota.

**Reset:**

Your quota will reset at midnight west cost USA time. No one will be able to access that view id until then.   Top tip when testing create a development view under the web property to request from then you wont blow out your production view.

Comment: Thank for your response. I am still bit confused regarding your first point "Pagination". As per My Code, i am sending one request to GA to fetch 4 metrics. so will GA calculate this request as 4 or more requests internally??

Comment: if you make a request and it returns 1000 rows.   But there is more data you will receive a nextpagetoken which you can use to request the next 1000 rows.   each request is one against your quota.